# How can I validate that has_many relations are not changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have an fairly typical **Order** model, that `has_many` **Lines**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lines
  validates_associated :lines
```

Once the order is completed, it should not be possible to change any attributes, or related lines (though you can change the status to not completed).

```
  validate do
    if completed_at.nil? == false && completed_at_was.nil? == false
      errors.add(:base, "You can't change once complete")
    end
  end
```

This works fine, *but*, if you add to, remove, or change the associated **Lines**, then this isn't prevented.

In my **Line** model, I have the following validation:

```
validate do
  if order && order.completed_at.nil? == false
    errors.add(:base, "Cannot change once order completed.")
  end
end
```

This successfully stops lines in a completed order being modified, and prevents a line being added to a completed order.

So I need to also prevent lines being taken out of a completed order. I tried this in the **Line** model:

```
validate do
  if order_id_was.nil? == false
    if Order.find(order_id_was).completed_at.nil? == false
      errors.add(:base, "Cannot change once order completed.")
    end
  end
end
```

This works fine to prevent a **Line** being taken out of an **Order** when modifying the **Line** directly. However when you are editing the **Order** and remove a **Line**, the validation never runs, as it has already been removed from the **Order**.

---

So... in short, how can I validate that the **Lines** associated with an **Order** do not change, and are not added to or removed?

I'm thinking I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the "Association Callbacks" section of [`ActiveRecord::Associations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), you'll see that there are several callbacks that you can add to your `has_many` definition:

- `before_add`
- `after_add`
- `before_remove`
- `after_remove`

Also from the same docs:

> Should any of the `before_add` callbacks throw an exception, the object does not get added to the collection. Same with the `before_remove` callbacks; if an exception is thrown the object doesn't get removed.

Perhaps you can add a callback method to `before_add` and `before_remove` that makes sure the order isn't frozen and throws an exception if it's not allowed.

```
has_many :lines,
         before_add:    :validate_editable!,
         before_remove: :validate_editable!

private

def validate_editable_lines!(line)
  # Define the logic of how `editable?` works based on your requirements
  raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved unless editable?(line)
end
```

Another thing worth trying would be to add a validation error and return `false` within `validate_editable_lines!` if your validation test fails. If that works, I'd recommend changing the method name to `validate_editable_lines` (sans `!` bang), of course. :)

Comment: Ah, this is close to perfect. Thank you. I would like it to result in an error rather than an exception if possible though, as you suggest at the end, however adding an error/returning false doesn't work. If you have any further thoughts on this that'd be great. Note, before_add/remove gets passed the line in args, so it's `validate_editable!(line)`.

Comment: A brief google appears to show this can't be done... so I think this is the way to go to enforce it, but I'll also need something in the controller.

Comment: You're right, it appears. You could probably throw your own exception and `rescue` it in the controller. It'll still stay pretty clean.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem, and to the best of my knowledge slightly tricky to solve.

Here is one approach: http://anti-pattern.com/dirty-associations-with-activerecord

Another approach which I think is slightly cleaner would be to simply check at the controller level before you add/remove a `Line`, and not to use validations.

Yet another approach is you can add `before_create` and `before_destroy` callbacks to `Line`, and check if the `Order` instance has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add a `locked` attribute to the model, and, after the order is completed set the value of `locked` to `true`.
Then, in the controller, add a `before_filter` that will be triggered before the update action so it would check the value of the `locked` flag. If it is set to `true` then raise an error/notification/whatever to the user that that line item cannot be changed.