# How can I check whether an associated array of records was changed in after_save callback for ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have code like the following:

```
   class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :associated_records
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :associated_records

     after_save :send_notification, if: :relevant_data_changed?

     def relevant_data_changed?
       return self.some_column_changed? || self.associated_records.changed?
     end

     def send_notification
       # Do stuff
     end
   end
```

I know I can check whether a column that is directly on the model changed (as I did in the example), and I think you can similarly even check whether a single nested object changed if there is a `has_one` relationship with that object (via `self.nested_model.changed?` I believe), but I can't figure out how to check whether an array of objects has changed, such as `associated_records` in my example.

EDIT: For the record, I did try the suggested solution from here: [Rails: if has_many relationship changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727130/rails-if-has-many-relationship-changed). But it does not work in the case where objects were only added or removed rather than actually changed.

Does anyone know of a way I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit more digging, it turns out that the proper way to do what I'm trying to do is with the `after_add` and `after_remove` callbacks.

[How can I validate that has_many relations are not changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746181/how-can-i-validate-that-has-many-relations-are-not-changed)

In my example, it would be something like:

```
has_many :associated_records, after_add: :send_notification

# This gets called for every new record added, even if multiple are
# added at once
def send_notification(new_record)
  # Do stuff with the new_record
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :associated_records, after_save :force_save_associated_records      

  def force_save_associated_records
    associated_records.map{|x| x.save! if x.changed?}
  end
end
```